# How to prove that Matrix $M$ is a Markov Matrix?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, matrix-equations, page-rank

I am learning the PageRanks algorithm, and came across a question which demands to prove that:

1. given a Markov matrix $M$, the following resulting matrix $A$ will also be a Markov matrix: [image: A]
2. the product of two Markov matrices is a Markov matrix.

How can one prove these two statements with an example in Python? Does anyone here has an idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Definitions are your friends.   What makes a matrix a Markov (transition) matrix?

Comment: sum of values of each column = 1?

Comment: We need a little more.  Combine the matrix entries being nonegative with column sums = 1 and that will be enough.